# Is there a way to password protect an individual table in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, passwords

I have one database called medtrack and I want to protect each users table, so say user1 has a table, table1, I want it to have a password, say password 1, and user2 has table, with password 2. Is there a way to do this, or should I just create individual databases?

Sorry if this question is stupid, I'm fairly new at this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate table for separate user then you need to use [grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) command to provide access to "user1" for "table1" and same with "user2" depending upon your application.

And you can also use [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) if you want to show only subset of table to the user.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any way, however you can encrypt the data in the table before saving.
Passwords are generally saved in encrypted form.

MD5 and SHA (1..512) are frequently used for one way encryption of passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set password at table level. Password are set at Server level. 
However you can protect these tables by giving only READ/Write permission to a specific MySQL user by:

```
Grant Select, Insert, Update on medtrack.* to 'mysql_user'@'mysql_host';
```